# categories and subcategories drodpwn list Issue in vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

I have category and subcategory dropdownlist, onchange category dropdown getting subcategory of selected category and category and subategory id stored in database.

But issue is in display subcategory option which selected at insert time.
how can i call vuejs method when edit popup modal open.
in vuejs method i wrote subcategory selected function based on selected category.

but i am unable to call this function when edit popup modal open, this function is inside vuejs methods

```
methods: {
    getcategories: function(){
    let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/getAllCategory';
        this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
        let $this = this;
        $this.categories = response.data;
        $this.id = response.data.id
        $this.name = response.data.name
        })
         .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    },

    selectSubCategory: function selectSubCategory(){

    var catId =  $("#categoryProduct").val();

    let $this = this;

    $this.axios.get('/getSubcategory', {
        params: {
        request: 'subcategory',
        id: catId
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
       $this.subcategories = response.data
       $this.id = response.data.id
       $this.name = response.data.name
    }); 
    }
}
```

and i called selectSubCategory function  as below code

```
$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
   selectSubCategory();
 });
```

but its gives error undefined function selectSubCategory.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It should be this.selectSubCategory();

Comment: @Riddhi : i was tried  with this - this.selectSubCategory();  ,but  its given error undefiend this.selectSubCategory()

Comment: Did u try using arrow function???$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', () => { 
   this.selectSubCategory();
 });

Comment: Also update selectSubCategory: function selectSubCategory() => selectSubCategory: function ()

Comment: @Riddhi: yes , i was tried this one also as you mantion but getting below              errorTypeError: _this is undefined and function not called.

Comment: @Riddhi: i am using ` ` in between { this.selectSubCategory(); } :  $(window).on('shown.bs.modal',() => `{ this.selectSubCategory(); }`); ,so error not comes but function not called.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses JQuery to trigger the custom event hidden.bs.modal so it is not easily caught by Vue (which I believe uses native events under the hood).

Since you have to have JQuery on a the page to use Bootstrap's native modal, just use JQuery to catch it. Assuming you add a ref="vuemodal" to your Bootstrap modal you can do something like this.

In template =>

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal" ref="vuemodal">
```

In Script =>
    new Vue({

```
  el:"#app",
  data:{
  },
  methods:{
    selectSubCategory(){
      //do something
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    $(this.$refs.vuemodal).on("shown.bs.modal", this.selectSubCategory)
  }
})
```